# Is it ok to ask questions with intuitively phrased titles, even if there are existing questions like that?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes when I look for something on Google, the search results are complete trash, or there are lots of questions on a similar topic, but not quite about what I'd like to know, after searching exclusively the SE sites and not finding anything, I ask a question on a corresponding SE site with title phrased like I would ask a normal person (who knows everything, so "normal" is relative).

Sometimes there really are questions about the same thing, so they are closed as duplicates.

Is this alright by the rules of SE?

Comment: Can you make an example?

Comment: Consider editing one of the existing questions to give it a better title.

Comment: @Pekka웃 an example: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87664/mastering-crushing-playing-steam-game-info-for-borderlands-2

Comment: @hammar if I was to find any myself prior to asking, I would

Comment: That looks like an okay question title to me, but then I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're asking. Are you asking whether it's fine to ask questions in natural language? Or whether it's fine to ask duplicates?

Comment: The present question doesn't really make sense without a list of titles.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'm asking if it is okay to ask them in natural language even if they're duplicates. Sometimes I know they are duplicates, sometimes not.

Comment: Either a question is really a duplicate (and you should not ask it) or it's not (and you should precisely focus on what makes it an original question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a question that is appropriate for a given Stack Exchange site, and can't find an answer to that question either via your favorite search engine or via the site's search box, then sure, post it on the site.
Use a title that makes sense to you, with the terms you find appropriate. And make sure the title and/or the body use the terms you were searching for so that like-minded people will find the question easily.

If you *do* find an answer to your question already posted, then no I don't think knowingly posting a duplicate is very productive.

What you should do then is edit the existing question so that it does contain the terms you were using. One way of doing this would be (for simple-enough cases) to simply add a rephrased version of the question.

> In other words, what do the mastering / crushing / playing terms in the Steam game info mean?

This wouldn't work for the specific question you link to but does in some circumstances. This might work (replacing the last sentence in the original question):

> I've also seen "crushing" and "playing" in the Steam game info box. Could someone explain what the statuses are and what the numbers mean?

Unfortunately the two formulations above invalidate the existing answer, so don't do that. (The answer only explains the numbers. Maybe your question isn't an exact duplicate after all?) If the numbers are the only important thing (I have no idea what this is all about), then a simple addition:

> I've also seen "crushing" and "playing" in the Stream info box, followed by similar numbers.

should make that question "findable" using your original search keywords.

If you can think of *no way at all* to include your search terms/phrases in the original question in a non-obtrusive way, posting a duplicate isn't *forbidden*. It should work, and it's not really disruptive to the site. But consider editing before.

Note: if you don't have full editing privileges, make sure you add a *detailed* edit summary. Explain exactly what you're doing and why.

Comment: Thanks, this will be my guide for future possible situations like this.